# What are defintions of Work Performance Data, Work Performance Information & Work Performance Reports, and their differences?

Tags: pmp, performance, pmbok

For the PMBOK 5th Edition.

Using following books for reference:
- Head First PMP 3rd Edition, Jennifer Greene, PMP & Andrew Stellman, PMP
- PMP Project Management Professional Exam Study Guide, Kim Heldman, PMP

I am trying to understand the definitions of the following terms, and I'm also trying to understand the differences between each of the following terms, and how they relate to each other, and whether or not they overlap:

-Work Performance Data

-Work Performance Information

-Work Performance Reports

Could someone please correct me if I'm wrong?

Work Performance Data seems to be raw data that we directly get from "Direct and Manage Project Work Process" like the following:

- % of work complete
- status of deliverables
- technical performance measurement
- actual start and finish date of activities ( schedule progress to date )
- number of change requests
- number of defects
- cost incurred to date

Is it correct to state that the Work Performance Data is raw data that basically tells us about work completed on the project to date?

Work Performance Information seems to go a step further, and yields the following data:

- forecasts for completion dates associated with activities
- forecasts for budget ( cost )

Is it correct to state that the Work Performance Information is forecast data that is based on raw data like Work Performance Data?

Work Performance Reports goes a step further by going to the giving more complex data like statistical data based on Work Performance Data and Work Performance Information, and Work Performance Reports could include status, reports, memos, updates, etc.

- Earned Value Calculations
- Variance Analysis

Are the above definitions, and explanation of differences between terms correct?

Answer (score 2):

I neither know nor care how the PMBoK defines these definitions but I would define them as follows:

Data:  Raw.
Information:  Raw data synthesized and interpreted such that findings are identified, conclusions drawn, questions answered, and alternatives and recommendations are developed.
Reporting:  Information displayed at the appropriate level, depth, breadth for others to consume.

Answer (score 0):

WPD is raw data.  For example, if you're making widgets, WPD includes the number you've made, schedule actual start and finish dates, but also measures such their weights, size or whatever you're measuring for quality control purposes.

WPI come from WPD.  WPI are CV, CPI, SV, etc.  WPI adds context to WPD.  For example, AC is raw data, but with no context, it doesn't mean much.  CPI, however gives context.

WPR are derived from WPI and might include pretty graphs for status reports for upper management. They might include recommendations.  WPR is intended decision-making, and for situational awareness.